# D3.js v3 foreignObject Html button doesn't work after 2 years no update of my code

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, foreignobject

In 2017, my code worked well as you see the buttons appeared on the page.

2017 screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

But by now, I had no idea why they disappeared as the following image shows.

2019 screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

I guess this may be for the button method I used, because the buttons needed to be inside the SVG of the map and chart, that was the only one method I found worked at 2017. The following is the code of the two buttons.

```
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
              resetButton.disabled=false;
              xZoom=d3.event.translate[0];
              yZoom=d3.event.translate[1];
              sZoom=d3.event.scale;
              svg1.selectAll(".mapSvg").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }
            svg
            .style({
              'border':'0px solid #000'
            })
            .call(zoom);
             svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
                .data("1")
                .enter()
                .append("foreignObject")
                .attr("class", "reset")
                .attr("float","left")
                .attr("x", width-60)
                .attr("y", 10)
                .append("xhtml:body")
                .html(function(d){ return "<form><input type=button class=button id=reset value=reset disabled=true /></form>"})
                .on("click",function(){
                  d3.transition().duration(250).tween("zoom", function() {
                    var si = d3.interpolate(sZoom, 1);
                    var xi = d3.interpolate(xZoom, 0);
                    var yi = d3.interpolate(yZoom, 0);
                      return function(t){
                        svg1.call(zoom.translate([xi(t),yi(t)]).scale(si(t)).event);
                      }
                  });
            }); 


deathdayChart.selectAll("foreignObject")
                        .data("select all deaths")
                        .enter()
                        .append("foreignObject")
                        .attr("class", "selectAllDays")
                        .attr("x", widthChart - 100)
                        .attr("y", 5)
                        .attr("width", 60)
                        .append("xhtml:body")
                        .html(function(d){ return "<form><input type=button class=button id=setDay value=reset /></form>"})
                        .on("click",updateDeaths);
```

Comment: `selectAll.data()` requires an array (or function or nothing) - you are providing a string, if you want to provide a placeholder value datum, use ["someString"], or better yet use  `svg.append("foreignObject")... ` rather than `svg.selectAll().data().enter().append(...` as from a quick glance what I see you don't use the datum in any event. As is no foreignObject should be entered and thus none displayed.

Comment: I tried both methods you mentioned, but neither of them works. And as the code worked well at 2017, I don't know why it suddenly doesn't work again.